# 'a' undeclared (first use in this function) Error

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm new to programming and I want to create a program that can print out the first n digits of pi, where n is specified by the user. What might be the reason for this issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_DIGITS 10

int main(void) {
    int pi[MAX_DIGITS] = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3};
    printf("How many digits of pi would you like to print? ");
    int digits;
    scanf("%d", &digits);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < digits) {
        printf("%d", array[i]);
        if (i == 0){
            printf(".");
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error message says exactly what is wrong. Your `printf` talks about `array[i]` but there is nothing called `array`.

Comment: The error and the code don’t seem to agree as there is no “a” identifier used). In any case, there is no “array” variable shown..

Comment: I do not understand the question. Could you please be more specific, like pasting here your compiler output/error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code inside your while loop is the problem.

```
   printf("%d", array[i]);
```

Your array is called pi whereas you have 'array' here, so just rename this to pi and it should work fine.

It **should** be i == 0, contrary to zywy's answer. You might want to make the condition `i == 0 && digits > 1` though so that you don't print a decimal point when you request one digit of pi.

On a side note, I don't think it's a good idea to have an array to store the digits of pi that you want, unless you have specific limits on the potential values of n the user can enter. Consider using the following formula to calculate digits of pi:

[image: Equation to calculate digits of pi]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do but
there is no array[i] declared. Is this what you want to do?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_DIGITS 10

int main(void) {
    int pi[MAX_DIGITS] = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3};
    printf("How many digits of pi would you like to print? ");
    int digits;
    scanf("%d", &digits);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < digits) {
        printf("%d", pi[i]);
        if (i == 0){
            printf(".");
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
  
    return 0;
}
```

also you should check if digits isn't more than MAX_DIGITS